# Time based notifications

Tags: notifications, appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

I am building an app which needs to send time-based notifications to the user.

I am using Notification Manager module and background services and pushing the notifications. This is working fine as long as the app is opened either in background or accessible.

Once I close the app, then notifications are not coming. How can I ensure that my service is running even though my app is closed and keep sending notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Start your service using **Titanium.Android.startService**
For Example,

app.js

```
var intent = Titanium.Android.createServiceIntent({
    url: 'myservice.js'
});
intent.putExtra('interval', 10000); // Service should run its code every 2 seconds.
intent.putExtra(Titanium.Android.EXTRA_DONT_KILL_APP, true);
Titanium.Android.startService(intent);
```

myservice.js

```
var intent = Ti.Android.createIntent({
   action: Ti.Android.ACTION_MAIN,
   className: 'com.testApp.TestappActivity',
   packageName: 'com.testApp'
});

intent.addCategory(Ti.Android.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);

var pending = Titanium.Android.createPendingIntent({
   intent: intent,
   flags: Titanium.Android.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
});

var notification = Titanium.Android.createNotification({
   contentTitle: 'Something Happened',
   contentText: 'Click to return to the application.',
   contentIntent: pending
});

Titanium.Android.NotificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

Also add service to your tiapp.xml,

```
<android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <services>
        <service url="myservice.js" type="interval" />
    </services>
</android>
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response. Let me try and get back to you.

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working.

1. Ti.Android.startService does not return the service. It returns void. Hence we cannot add the event listener of taskremoved to it.

So when i close the app, then notifications stopped coming.

Comment: Oh yes..That's by mistake..just try starting the service through startService method. Don't add event listener to it. Have edited code.

Comment: For more help, read this doc http://docs.appcelerator.com/platform/latest/#!/guide/Android_Services-section-43287937_AndroidServices-TypesofServices